# Extract version number from string, optimal way?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, version

I have that string:

```
<span class="cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome-container cloud-body-text__small">Chrome v. <span class="cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome-version">74.0.3729.131</span></span>
```

I just want the version number. I'm wondering what you guys think would be the optimal way to isolate it.

Right now i'm doing it via REGEX like this :

```
-match "\d{1,}[\.]\d{1,}[\.]\d{1,}[\.]\d{1,}"
```

(1 or more Numbers, dot, 1 or more Numbers, dot, 1 or more Numbers, dot, 1 or more Numbers)

It works perfectly however what if they were to change the version naming?

Another way to see it would be to isolate what is between

```
<span class="cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome-version">
```

and

```
</span>
```

Just looking for your opinion on the safest way to approach this.

FYI : I know I can use Invoke-Webrequest to fetch the actual element but for some reason that command hangs on this particular google URL so I had to make do with just fetching the source code with an InternetExplorer.Application COM objet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your string to xml:

```
$XML = [XML]'<span class="cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome-container cloud-body-text__small">Chrome v. <span class="cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome-version">74.0.3729.131</span></span>'
```

---

```
> [version]$xml.span.span.'#text'

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
74     0      3729   131
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use with -match .

```
$str =  "<span class=cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome-container cloud-body- 
text__small>Chrome v. <span class=cloud-browser-downloads__dl-row-chrome- 
  version>74.0.3729.131</span></span>"
 $regex = [regex] "\d{1,}[\.]\d{1,}[\.]\d{1,}[\.]\d{1,}"

$found = $str -match $regex

if ($found) {
 $ip = $matches[0]
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I was already using, i didn't put all the matches code but only the regex. However the XML solution above is so cool I'm using it now :). Thanks